# Не выставляется PCIe x16 3.0

Tags: видеокарта

Купил с рук видеокарту rx 6600 с гарантией. У продавца всё было нормально (выставился режим PCIe x16 4.0), однако у меня работает только PCIe x8 3.0 на данной системе: b450m s2h (мат. плат.), rx 6600 (видюха), amd ryzen 5 1600 (проц) и m2 NVME (ssd). По системе не может быть PCIe 4.0 (это понятно), но считал, что PCIe x16 3.0 будет работать.
Проверял на другой видюхе rx 570 8gb (там всё норм PCIe x16 3.0); вытаскивал m2 NVME и пробовал без него (проц поддерживает 16 PCIe линий, поэтому думал, что на видюху не досталось), однако и это не помогло.
Не знаю в чём проблема, однако в GPU-Z не показывает даже возможным работу на PCIe x16 3.0.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также обновил BIOS, но тоже не помогло.

Comment: а у rx 6600 в принципе разведены х16? Вроде у rx 6600 всего 8 линий и должно быть: https://www.techpowerup.com/review/asus-radeon-rx-6600-xt-strix-oc/36.html

Comment: И в правду, как увидел существуют 2 версии с 8x и 16x, однако на коробке этой видюхе написан x16

Comment: Видимо в ДНС, решили поправить описание и ещё в кое-каких источниках. Спасибо что разъяснили.

Comment: тут приходится различать интерфейс как физический объект - габаритно это вполне может быть x16. Но электрически может быть подключено меньше. Описания у розничных продавцов в таких случаях, конечно, скорее всего будут с ошибками. Не тот уровень, чтобы по тысячам позиций в каталоге проверку фактов устраивать. Да ещё и маркетинг мешать будет (как это, у всех х16, а тут вы хотите х8 написать?! в два раза меньше же не купят!)

Answer (score 0):

Помог комментарий. Тут была моя ошибка в не понимании PCI-E. То есть существует порт  PCI-E (то, как выглядит разъём на плате) и линии PCI-E (то, сколько есть контактов в порту или видюхе).
В моём случае считал, что порт и линии всегда одинаковы, но это не так.